# Digikam: what shortcut for "confirm face tag" button?

Tags: face-detection, keyboard-shortcuts, digikam

I'm confirming face tags on my pictures. There are two cases:

1. I'm placing new tag. In that case I just type tag name and press `Enter` key. Everything is working as expected: tag is assigned.
2. I'm assigning existing tag. In that case if I press `Enter` after typing tag name the typed tag name is erased to initial state, like one on picture:

[image]

My question is following: what should I press after typing name of existing face tag to assign it to picture?

P.S. Digikam has version 5.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. I just left-click on "Confirm" and that's it.
digiKam doesn't seem to like 'Enter' that much.